# Selecting text from link using parent-child method

Tags: javascript, parent-child

I have a code as below;

```
<td class="class1" colspan="5">
<a class="class2" href="LINKLINK">TEXTDATA</a>
</td>
```

I can select the link text by taking `('.class2').text()`. But I want to grab the text using children method. How can I grab the same if I have no class for the link (class2) and have only class1. I think the solution will be something like `('.class1').children('a').text()`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.class1').children('a').text();
```

would do the job.  Remember though, that `$(.class1')` will match every element on the page that has the class `class1`.  So you'll get the text for all of the inner links.

You could also do:

```
$('.class1:first').children('a').text();
$('.class1').first().children('a').text();
$('.class1').find('a').text(); //checks all descendants
var context = $('.class1')[0];
$('a', context).text();
```

there are many more ways... I encourage you to check out the selectors and traversing section on the [jQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com/).

Good luck!